# How to lookup id values in groups of rows of the same dataset using analytic window SQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

```
--Dataset Name: Jobs
week   date    job_id
----------------------
wk1    01/15   300
wk1    01/15   301
wk1    01/15   302
wk2    01/22   300 
wk2    01/22   302
wk2    01/22   303
wk2    01/22   304
wk3    01/29   302
wk3    01/29   304
wk3    01/29   305
```

I have a dataset like above. I want to create 3 additional columns namely:

is_job_id_present_in_wk1

is_job_id_present_in_wk2

is_job_id_present_in_wk3

I want to write a SQL query that marks each row as 1 or 0 for each of the three new columns. I don't want to use a self join. I would like to make use of some analytic window function.

For example, for the first row in the given dataset, the values for is_job_id_present_in_wk1, is_job_id_present_in_wk2 and is_job_id_present_in_wk3 will be 1 (because job_id 300 was present in all three weeks).

For the second row in the given dataset, the values for is_job_id_present_in_wk1 will be 1, is_job_id_present_in_wk2 will be 0 and is_job_id_present_in_wk3 will be 0 (because job_id 301 was present only in all week 1).

Tried till now:

```
SELECT week, date, job_id
       , CASE WHEN job_id = 
                            FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN week='wk1' THEN job_id ELSE NULL END) OVER(ORDER BY job_id rows between current row and current row) 
 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as is_job_id_present_in_wk1
 FROM jobs;
```

Comment: What did the query at the bottom of your question result in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT week, date, job_id,
        max( case when week = 'wk1' then 1 else 0 end )
            over (partition by  job_id) as is_job_id_present_in_wk1,
        max( case when week = 'wk2' then 1 else 0 end )
            over (partition by job_id) as is_job_id_present_in_wk2,
        max( case when week = 'wk3' then 1 else 0 end )
            over (partition by  job_id) as is_job_id_present_in_wk2
FROM jobs;
```

Try also this version:

```
SELECT week, date, job_id
       , CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM jobs job1 
                           WHERE job1.job_id = jobs.job_id AND job1.week = 'wk1' )
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as is_job_id_present_in_wk1
       , CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM jobs job1 
                           WHERE job1.job_id = jobs.job_id AND job1.week = 'wk2' )
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as is_job_id_present_in_wk2
       , CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM jobs job1 
                           WHERE job1.job_id = jobs.job_id AND job1.week = 'wk3' )
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as is_job_id_present_in_wk3
 FROM jobs;
```

because it could be faster than the verion with analytic functions, esppecially when you create a composite index on job_id + week columns.

Comment: I had already had the second solution working. I was just waiting to figure out the logic using window functions -- that's your first solution. 
I should have been able to write this. Aaah. Thanks a lot